# Почему при смене языка не меняется название Фрагмента?

Tags: java, android

Почему при смене языка не меняется название Фрагмента?

----------Class Application

```
public class BaseApp extends Application{
    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context=getApplicationContext();

    }
}
```

----------Class Constans просто коснаты

```
    public final class Constants {

    // Screen titles
    public static final String LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = BaseApp.context.getString(R.string.const_login);
    public static final String MY_LEARNING_FRAGMENT_TAG = BaseApp.context.getString(R.string.const_my_learning);
}
```

---------- Функция которая меняет язык.

```
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Configuration configuration = BaseApp.context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(myLocale);
    getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToMainActivity);
    getActivity().finish();
```

Вообщем все  это дело работает только после перезапуска приложения. Я как понимаю что - то не то с классом Constants. Как можно сделать так чтобы работало

Comment: не боишься хранить Контект в статик переменной ?

Comment: @KolinLoures если это Application Context - не страшно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статические константы не переинициализируются при смене языка. Да и не должны, они же константы. Все будет прекрасно работать, если Вы будете выставлять заголовки фрагментам не через константы, а напрямую через `BaseApp.context.getString(R.string.const_login)`.

А при перезапуске все работает, потому что приложение удаляется из памяти и запускается снова, что приводит к инициализации статических полей впоследствии.